# Criar uma palavra em cruz C++

Tags: c++, string

[image: Armando]Quem me conseguia dar uma ajuda nisto?

Vou pôr um exemplo do que quero.

```
A     A
 R   R
  M M
   A
  N N
 D   D
O     O
```

Mas os mesmos espaços tem de estar na horizontal, como na vertical, tem que ficar em quadrado.

Obrigado

Comment: Isso é um exercício de faculdade ou algo semelhante?

Comment: Tem que ser C++ ou pode ser C? Há algum outro tipo de restrição, tal como classes ou funções específicas a utilizar ou não utilizar ou algum tipo de estrutura que o programa tem que seguir? Ou qualquer coisa que o compilador aceite e que produza esse resultado vale?

Comment: Eu tenho que fazer isto em c++eu estou tentando fazer com for, qq ajuda é bem vinda, mesmo que seja em outra linguagemeu já percebi que tenho que fazer a contagem por linhas e a separação por char... mas não estou a lá xegar.

Comment: Minha sugestão é primeiro tentar fazer uma das hélices da cruz, depois a outra, e depois combinar as duas. Repare por exemplo que na primeira hélice, há 0 espaços antes do caractere 0, 1 espaço antes do caractere 1, e assim por diante. Na segunda, há (tamanho-1) espaços antes do caractere 0, (tamanho-2) antes do caractere 1, etc. Outra forma de pensar é que há uma matriz de espaços em branco ("tamanho" linhas e "tamanho" colunas), e a letra N ocupa tanto a coluna N quanto a tamanho-N-1 na linha N. Comece imprimindo só os espaços, depois use `if`s para escolher entre um espaço e uma letra.

Comment: Isto é imprimido no terminal? Ou em um GUI? De detalhes por favor.

Comment: Em terminal CMD, vou deixar aqui o printScreen

Comment: @RubenPais isto deve ser informado na pergunta, edite ela e especifique isto :)

Comment: Obrigado @Guilherme Nascimento .... mas já resolvi... mas para a proxima vou ter isso em consideração . Obrigada

Answer (score 3):

Isso serve?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const string c = "ARMANDO";
    int t = c.length() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= t; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= t; j++) {
            cout << (i == j || i == t - j ? c[i] : ' ');
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

O truque é que `i == j` é a diagonal principal e `i == t - j` é a diagonal secundária.

Answer (score 1):

Eu, ontem ao fim de muita luta consegui.

Quero agradecer a todos que ajudaram e me deram me ideias.

Obrigado.

Deixo aqui a resolução.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Introduza nome: ";
    string name;
    getline(cin, name);


    for(int line = 0; line < name.size(); line++){
        for(int space=0; space < name.size();space++){
            if(space == line){
                cout << name[line];
            }
            else{
                if(space == name.size()-line-1){
                    cout << name[line];
                }
                else{
                    cout << " ";
                }
            }
        }   
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: RESULTADO]